# jquery sparkline with array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparklines

I am trying to use jquery sparkline.
THis is what I am trying to do.

```
var values = [{value:123}, {value:234}, {value:345}];

// Draw a sparkline for the #sparkline element
$('#sparkline').sparkline(values.value, {
type: "pie",
// Map the offset in the list of values to a name to use in the tooltip
tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} ({{percent.1}}%)',
tooltipValueLookups: {
    'offset': {
        0: 'First',
        1: 'Second',
        2: 'Third'
    }
   },
});
```

but for this data format sparkline is not able to draw.
what change I have to do in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to extract values from your array before creating your sparkline.

You can use the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function :

```
$('#sparkline').sparkline(values.map(function(o) { return o.value}), {
   ...
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj6fB/181/)